# Remove unique duplicate in multiple array and sum them Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have data like this:

```
var data1 = ["RFCC","HCC","RFCC"];
var data2 = [1,1,1];
```

I want to remove unique duplicate and sum the number based on removed unique, so the result should be like this:

```
var data1 = ["RFCC","HCC"];
var data2 = [2,1];
```

If possible, maybe someone could help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
var data2 = [];
data1 = data1.filter((item, i)=>{
 var _i = data1.indexOf(item);
 if( _i === i){
  data2.push(1);
  return true;
 } else {
  data2[_i] = data2[_i] + 1;
  return false;
 }
})

console.log(data1, data2);
```